# AWS cloudwatch logs datetime_format config combine multiple lines into one line

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I use aws cloudwatch to collect aws ecs farget task's logs.

The config is in the following pic:

[image: log format in task definition]

And I get the following logs, it is wired. Some lines with datetime is combined in one log. I think every log starts with datetime should be seen as one single log.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `%L` option of `awslogs-datetime-format` has incorrect documentation. I had the same problem and then looked at the driver source code and `%L` matches `\.\d{3}` (here's [a source link](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/785b3e32876e10d638d9b1bae00e3f340a2f47ec/daemon/logger/awslogs/cloudwatchlogs.go#L209)).

This means the pattern already matches a literal `.`  at the start of the pattern. You may change the format like this and it will work.

```
awslogs-datetime-format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%L'
```

Comment: Current documentation seems to be correct in https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#awslogs-datetime-format, but this is very tricky.